# draw a few lines on an image with mouse move

Tags: vb.net, drawing

I want to draw a few lines on an image
Using mouse move in vb.net.
My problem is that when I start drawing the next line, the previous line disappears!
Can anyone help me?
I put my code along with a photo of run my project

```
Dim st, en As New Point
Dim p As Pen
Private mouseButtonPressed As Boolean = False

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    p = New Pen(Color.Black, 2)
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    g.DrawLine(p, st, en)
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
    mouseButtonPressed = False
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If mouseButtonPressed Then
        PictureBox1.Invalidate()
        en = e.Location
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        st = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
        mouseButtonPressed = True
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: GIF of my run project]

Comment: You draw the line when you paint, but paint only draws one line.  When you change to start and end points and re-paint, it only has one line to paint.  Maybe create a collection of points and add to that collection on MouseUp then draw all lines in collection in Paint

Answer (score 0):

You can store the lines in a list as they get completed, then draw all the previous lines when you are drawing the live one

```
Private st, en As New Point
Private mouseButtonPressed As Boolean = False

Private lines As New List(Of (st As Point, en As Point))

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    Dim p = New Pen(Color.Black, 2)
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    g.DrawLine(p, st, en)
    For Each line In lines
        g.DrawLine(p, line.st, line.en)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
    mouseButtonPressed = False
    lines.Add((st, en))
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If mouseButtonPressed Then
        PictureBox1.Invalidate()
        en = e.Location
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        st = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
        mouseButtonPressed = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The list holds `Tuple(of Point, Point)`